# English Language & Usage showed in two lines in the Top Network Sites section of StackExchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com

Right part of the [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) contains a list of Top Network Sites. *English Language & Usage* looks weird in this list:

> [image: ELU]

I.e. contains some extra ending `St...` on the second line.

In the mobile Chrome (iOS) text fits in a single line:

> [image: ios]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed ([within a few months after this bug report](http://web.archive.org/web/20170701203846/https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime)) by omitting the superfluous "Stack Exchange" after site names:

[image]

It will become a problem again if sites with longer names, like [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) make it to the top ten sites, but that is rather unlikely.